# Query number of arguments from a lambda/function

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I would like to query a lambda/function about how much parameters it uses.
Small (pseudo) example code:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
bool visitAll( InputIterator f, InputIterator l, Predicate p, UserData* d=nullptr)
{
    for(; f != l; ++f)
    {
        if(number_of_arguments(p) == 1)
        {
            if(!p(*f))
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!p(*f, *d))
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the function I am asking for is `number_of_arguments(...)`.
I have been searching in the Closure and std::function reference, but did not find a clue about a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not possible, and if you look closely at the standard library functions taking a predicate (for example [the standard library algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)) you will see that none of them have that kind of functionality, instead they have different overloads if they need different predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the code as you posted does not make much sense, as anyway either `p(*f)` or `p(*f, *d)` would fail to compile. Therefore you need to split this into two templates, and then you can test the number of arguments of `Predicate` using a rather straightforward SFINAE approach:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
bool visitAll( InputIterator f, InputIterator l, Predicate p, UserData* d=nullptr, 
   decltype(declval<Predicate>()(*declval<InputIterator>()),1) unused = 1)
{
    cout << "1" << std::endl;
    for(; f != l; ++f)
    {
        if(!p(*f))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
bool visitAll( InputIterator f, InputIterator l, Predicate p, UserData* d=nullptr, 
   decltype(declval<Predicate>()(*declval<InputIterator>(), declval<UserData>()),1) unused = 1)
{
    cout << "2" << std::endl;
    for(; f != l; ++f)
    {
        if(!p(*f, *d))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> a{1,2};
const auto t = [](int x){ return 1;};
const auto t2 = [](int x, UserData y){ return 1;};

UserData d;
visitAll(a.begin(), a.end(), t);
visitAll(a.begin(), a.end(), t2, &d);
```

Of course, you can use `std::bind` to avoid code duplication by calling first version from the second.

---

Another approach is to use code similar to how `std::bind` checks that it got needed number of arguments:

```
template<typename _Func>
struct noa_helper { 
};

template<typename _Ret, typename... _Args>
struct noa_helper<_Ret (*)(_Args...)> {
    static int noa() { return sizeof...(_Args); }
};

template<class F>
int number_of_arguments(F f) {
    return noa_helper<typename std::decay<F>::type>::noa();
}

void foo();
int bar(int x, int y);
...
std::cout << number_of_arguments(foo) << std::endl; // prints 0
std::cout << number_of_arguments(bar) << std::endl; // prints 2
```

This works only for real functions, not lambdas, nor `std::function`, though probably some more template magic can make it work for the latter two categories.

Comment: The pseudo code should visualize the intent only, of course. Thanks for the good answer! Even though the code runs into a segfault, only a small change was necessary to make it run:

    UserData d;
    visitAll(a.begin(), a.end(), t2, &d);

Otherwise, the nullptr would have been dereferenced.